# Ray run multiple threads in async actor

Tags: python, python-asyncio, ray

I am utilizing the `ray` library and am creating multiple actors for process-level parallelism. I would like to utilize thread-level parallelism within an async actor. I see from the [docs](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/actors/async_api.html) that if an actor has any async method, it will be registered as an async actor.

Furthermore, with the `asyncio.to_thread` function, one can run a regular function as a coroutine on a [separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316863/is-asyncio-to-thread-method-different-to-threadpoolexecutor) using the default `ThreadPoolExecutor`. And the default concurrency for async actors in `ray` is 1000, and can be configured as well, as per the docs.

Therefore, as I understand, it is possible to run multiple threads called within an async method in a `ray` async actor using the `asyncio.to_thread` method. I want to know if this is indeed the case, and if not, how can I utilize thread-level parallelism within a `ray` async actor? Similarly, does creating a thread using the `threading` library inside a method for a `ray` async actor actually work and spawn threads, or is the concurrency limited?

Edit:
Took a look at these links, and they may be of use:
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/31879
[How to make an actor do two things simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937456/how-to-make-an-actor-do-two-things-simultaneously)